# Return collected results from inner nested loops

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm trying to use Java8 streams to iterate over 2 lists and accumulate the results in the inner loop and eventually return `Multimap<String,String>`.

Here is a snippet:

```
private Multimap<String, String> processUsers(List<Organization> organizations, List<User> users) {
    return organizations.stream() //
        .map(organization-> users.stream()
            .filter(user -> organization.exist(user))
            .collect(MultimapCollector.toMultimap(User::role, User::id))
        );
}
```

This doesn't build, because it return `Stream<Object>`.
How to fix this method to collect and return MultiMap from the method.

Comment: What is the issue you are facing now?

Comment: I don't see a question, just a general statement about what you're trying to do

Comment: Your method reference syntax looks wrong. `user::` should probably be `User::`.

Comment: `users.streams()
            .filter(user -> organizations.exist(user))
            .collect(toMap(User::role, User::id));`

Comment: All your comments are fair enough, it was just a code snippet I altered for the sake of the problem I have. Updated question to be more accurate.

Answer (score 1):

Stream over the users first, not the organizations:

```
return users.stream()
    .filter(user -> organizations.stream().anyMatch(org -> org.exist(user)))
    .collect(MultimapCollector.toMultimap(User::role, User::id));
```